# Get values of given coordinates in Matlab

Tags: matlab

If I have the given coordinates `[1 2; 4 5]` and

```
s = [
     0.0    0.4    0.5    0.6    0.9
     0.4    0.0    0.3    0.4    0.5
     0.5    0.3    0.0    0.5    0.8
     0.6    0.4    0.5    0.0    0.6
     0.9    0.5    0.8    0.6    0.0
     ]
```

I want the following results:

- `A` should contain the values of the coordinates and the inverse coordinates. 
  i.e in this example, `A` contains the values of `(1,2)`, `(2,1)`, `(4,5)`, `(5,4)`. That is: `A=[0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6]`.
- `B` contains the remaining values, so `B=[0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0, 0.5, 0.8,  0.4, 0.5, 0, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8, 0.6, 0]`.

So far I have the following code:

```
linindices = sub2ind(size(s), coordinates(:, 1), coordinates(:, 2))'; 
A = s(linindices)
B = s(setdiff(1:numel(s), linindices))
```

but that only calculates `A=[0.4,0.6]`.
How can I get the inverse coordinates too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are almost there. The only thing is getting the inverse coordinates- you can do it by the command `fliplr`.

Here you can see how it can be done, with the whole code and the results. The critic line is for `Av`:

```
    c=[1 2; 4 5];
    s=[0 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.9
    0.4 0 0.3 0.4 0.5
    0.5 0.3 0 0.5 0.8
    0.6 0.4 0.5 0 0.6
    0.9 0.5 0.8 0.6 0];
    Av=[c; fliplr(c)]
    Ac=s(sub2ind(size(s),A(:,1),A(:,2)))
    B=s(setdiff(1:numel(s),sub2ind(size(s),A(:,1),A(:,2))))'


Av =

     1     2
     4     5
     2     1
     5     4


Ac =

    0.4000
    0.6000
    0.4000
    0.6000


B =

         0
    0.5000
    0.6000
    0.9000
         0
    0.3000
    0.4000
    0.5000
    0.5000
    0.3000
         0
    0.5000
    0.8000
    0.6000
    0.4000
    0.5000
         0
    0.9000
    0.5000
    0.8000
         0
```

Comment: Could you try to describe what you are doing and not just include the code without any comments? That would help to understand your code. Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much
but if i want to get 20% from values of

Comment: of B so how can i get this result

Comment: You mean that you want to divide B by 5? like `B=B/5;`?